# \w in PHP preg_replace covers only second byte of UTF-8 chars

Tags: php, regex, unicode, utf-8

we have this code:

```
$value = preg_replace("/[^\w]/", '', $value);
```

where `$value` is in utf-8. After this transformation first byte of multibyte characters is stripped. How to make \w cover UTF-8 chars completely?

Sorry, i am not very well in PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this function instead...http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-ereg-replace.php

Comment: I would rather advise *not* to use `mb_ereg_replace`. It is built on the deprecated `ereg_replace`. See http://php.net/ereg_replace

Answer (score 6):

You could [try with the /u modifier](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php):

> This modifier turns on additional functionality of PCRE that is incompatible with Perl. Pattern strings are treated as UTF-8. This modifier is available from PHP 4.1.0 or greater on Unix and from PHP 4.2.3 on win32. UTF-8 validity of the pattern is checked since PHP 4.3.5.

If that won't do, try

- [`mb_ereg_replace`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-ereg-replace.php) - Replace regular expression with multibyte support

instead.

Answer (score 4):

There is this nasty [`u` modifier to pcre patterns in PHP](http://de.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php). It states that the regex is encoded in UTF8, but I found that it treats the *input* as UTF8, too.

Comment: This answer has been added to the [Stack Overflow Regular Expression FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/2736496), under "Modifiers".

Answer (score 2):

Append `u` to regex, to turn on the multibyte unicode mode of PCRE:

```
$value = preg_replace("/[^\w]/u", '', $value);
```

#### Corollary

In unicode mode, PCRE expects everything is multibyte and if it is not then there *will* be problems meeting deadlines.  Therefore, to convert anything to UTF-8 (and drop any unconvertible junk), we first use:

```
$value = iconv( 'ISO-8859-1', 'UTF-8//IGNORE//TRANSLIT', $i );
```

to clean and prep the input.

Because everything can be encoded into ISO-8859-1 (even if some obscure characters appear incorrectly), and since most web browsers run natively in 8859 (unless told to use UTF-8), we've found this function as a general, safe, effective method to 'take anything, drop any junk, and convert into UTF-8'.

mb_ereg_* is deprecated as of 5.3.0 -- so using those functions is not the right way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Use `[^\w]+` instead of `[^\w]`

You can also use `\W` in place of `[^\w]`